# How could I add and update data in random order in a two-dimension matrix in Java

Tags: java, matrix, arraylist, addition

for example the input is: (row, column, weight), such as (0,2,10.0) ,(1,2,3.0), (2,1,11.3), (1,2, 15.0)

the result should be:

> 0 1 2
>
> 0 . . 10.0
>
> 1 . . 15.0
>
> 2 . 11.3 .

(the data would be both **inserted** and **updated**)

I have noticed that it could not be done by simply using **add(index i, elements e)** or **set()** method provided by **Arraylist** in Java. Because it would throw *:IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index > size())*   for instance, when I try to insert (0,2,5.0) after inserting (0,0,3.0).

Comment: Do you know the maximum dimensions up-front? Do you *want* to use a list, with values using the boxed type `Double`? Or is that just your attempt to handle the unknown size and order? Are you going to mingle reads and writes to this matrix, or read in the whole thing before you start using its data? Will the entire matrix be filled in, or do you need to represent undefined values? Is there a default value to be used, or do you need to recognize that an element is unspecified? How sparse is the data?

Comment: I assume that the input is unknown size and unordered. The code reads the input from a file and turn it into a matrix.

Comment: Can you answer the other questions?

Comment: Thanks! The default value could be a dot (or something like this). And I guess I could use a 2D arraylist to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do with an `ArrayList` is to add `null` elements as needed to increase the size before trying to set an element at a given index.

```
private final List<List<Double>> matrix = new ArrayList<>();

public OptionalDouble set(int i, int j, double value) {
    while (i >= matrix.size()) matrix.add(new ArrayList<>());
    List<Double> row = matrix.get(i);
    while (j >= row.size()) row.add(null);
    Double old = row.set(j, value);
    return (old == null) ? OptionalDouble.empty() : OptionaDouble.of(old);
}

public OptionalDouble get(int i, int j) {
    List<Double> row = (i < matrix.size()) ? matrix.get(i) : Collections.emptyList();
    Double value = (j < row.size()) ? row.get(j) : null;
    return (value == null) ? OptionalDouble.empty() : OptionalDouble.of(value);
}
```

This is likely to perform quite poorly on large matrices, because of all the object creation performed here, and the poor locality of reference.

If possible, a contiguous array of primitive `double` elements will be better for large, dense data sets.

Comment: The opportunities to optimize this depend on the answers to my comment on the question.